# Need to make the list view on the vertically center for Drawer Layout in Android

Tags: android, android-listview, drawerlayout

I have design a Drawer Layout which contains some options on a list(basically menu name and an icon). But i am not able to make the list view on the vertical center of the Drawer Layout. Here is my total xml layout:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- The main content view -->

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <include
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            layout="@layout/header" />

        <RelativeLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/pink_header"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="5dip" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tot_detail_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="Talk of Town Details"
                android:textColor="#222222"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="sans" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/feature_detail_title"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/drawer_btn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_drawer"
                    android:visibility="visible" />


            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tot_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:textColor="#222222"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:typeface="sans" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image_tot_detail"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/image_frame"
                    android:padding="1dip"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tot_time"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:textColor="#222222"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:typeface="sans" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tot_loc"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:textColor="#222222"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:typeface="sans" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tot_Desc"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Description:"
                    android:textColor="#0C7DAF"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:typeface="sans" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tot_Desc_details"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:textColor="#222222"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:typeface="sans" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
    </FrameLayout>
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:background="#343434"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector_drawer"
        android:divider="#ffffff"
         />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here is the drawer layout java code:

```
 mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

            // load slide menu items
            navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

            // nav drawer icons from resources
            navMenuIcons = getResources()
                    .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

            mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

            navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

            // adding nav drawer items to array
            // Home
            navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
            // Find People
            navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
            // Photos
            navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));

            if(strTableBook.equals("yes"))
            {
                // Table Booking
                navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1), true, "22"));
            }

            if(strGuestList.equals("yes"))
            {
                 // Guest List
                navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
            }

            if(strBuyNow.equals("yes"))
            {
                //Buy now
                navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1), true, "50+"));
            }

            Log.d("Testing", "here is 11111");
            // Recycle the typed array
            navMenuIcons.recycle();

            // setting the nav drawer list adapter
            adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                    navDrawerItems);
            mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
            mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());
            Log.d("Testing", "here is 22222");

            // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
//          getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
//          getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

            Log.d("Testing", "here is 33333");
            mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                    R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
                    R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                    R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
            )
            {
                public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
//                  getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                    // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                    invalidateOptionsMenu();
                }

                public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
//                  getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                    // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                    invalidateOptionsMenu();
                }
            };
            Log.d("Testing", "here is 444444");
            mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
```

And here is the click event for the Drawer List Item:

```
/**
 * Slide menu item click listener
 * */
private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
        ListView.OnItemClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        displayView(position);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }
}
```

It is coming like this:

[image]

Can anyone help me to make it on center.

Thanks..

Comment: what it looks like then?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

your ListView height is match_parent so setting layout_gravity to center_vertical wont make a difference try to set gravity center_vertical instead that will make listview content vertically centered.

```
    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:background="#343434"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector_drawer"
    android:divider="#ffffff"
     />
```

This should work but if not try this:

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:background="#343434" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="#343434"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="#ffffff"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector_drawer" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Change:

```
mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
```

to:

```
mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
```

Comment: Thanks, it is working. One more thing i need here. I am trying to add a horizontal line before and after the listview. How can i do it. Inside the Linear layout i have tried to add. But listview is vanishing from the layout as multiple child is not allowed probably inside the drawer view.

Comment: Unfortunately your solution is not working. As in the Drawer layout we can't add another layout it is crashing on the click event for list view

Comment: This is the exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$LayoutParams

Comment: what exactly are trying to do?? can you post your current code?/

Comment: This exception i am getting while clicking the list item. I will update the drawer code

Comment: also post on item click of listview

Comment: Yes updated. Did you ever worked on Drawer Layout? Because this is regarding the Drawer Layout..

Comment: You can follow this link: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

Comment: check my edit. I have used DrawerLayout and have good understanding.